# Unserialize class whose definition has changed

Tags: java, serialization

I made a mistake that I need to find a way to recover from.  I am working on an investigation project that requires a large set of samples. I am out of town for the week so I took some samples and used serialization save the data so I could use it while I am away.  In my rush to make progress I guess I changed the base class of the sample class structure and now I can't read the samples any longer.  I can't remember what I changed in the base class.

Is there any way to recover from this.  I am going to try using the reflection api.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

---

I am also attempting to use jdeserialize and I am having no luck.  To get started I am using code like:

```
String thePath = getPath();
jdeserialize my = new jdeserialize(thePath);

List con = my.getContent();
System.out.println("Size: " + con.size());
```

always tells me zero.  Is there a good example somewhere?

The error message is:

> `com.sig.ccm.util.LearningFrame; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -8423641452900611674, local class serialVersionUID = 6525488225233160191`

Comment: Did you make any data changes? Or will some serial version ID hack work?

Comment: have you checked that? https://code.google.com/p/jdeserialize/

Comment: In most modern IDEs you can browse the chronology of your changes and revert safely. Tedious, but that might be an option. That is, assuming source control is not involved.

Comment: You can easily create a new class that "looks like" your serialized class to the VM.  For starters, 1) Make sure your "new class" is as similar as possible to the original class, 2) Make sure the serialVersionUID is the same.  Check out this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-5things1/.  And be sure to get the [JD-GUI](http://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip) to analyze your class in greater detail.

Comment: I am out of town and the internet here isn't very good.  I didn't make any changes to the data itself.  I must have made a change to the base class.  I just downloaded the jdeserialize, thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't state what error you got, but if it involved the `serialVersionUID` value, you just have to change it, or define it, to the 'expected' value given in the error message.

If on the other hand you changed data types or inheritance of  the base class there is nothing you can do except revert the changes.

Comment: I have to admit I was sloppy when I started this, I had to make too much progress in too little time before I left.  I didn't define the serialVersionId.  I tried to define it and change it to either value and the error message values are too large.

Comment: @Sting What does "the error message values are too large" mean?  What happens when you put `static final long serialVersionUID = -8423641452900611674L;` in your class and try to deserialize the saved data?

Comment: It means I am not thinking clearly, I didn't read why eclipse didn't like when I tried this.  I did it too fast and inadvertently had a space between the number and the L.  Thanks for your help.  I can now read the samples.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you should consider upvoting it, and if you consider it correct you should also consider accepting it.